# How to merge two individuals cells into a singular combined value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a program that I need to merge two cells into a singular cell. The input .csv file is shown below

```
12 00 0E 00 57 23
57 23 02 23 57 0A
2D 16 0C 5A 2D 16
```

This is a small excerpt of the input file I have. I am currently trying to create a new column where the values are

```
0012
000E
2357
2357
2302
0A57
162D
5A0C
162D
```

ie the second value precedes the first, is combined, and continues down the input file, left and down. I am not very familiar with Pandas and was hoping there was anyone with any ideas with a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the underlying numpy array and `reshape`:

```
import io

t = '''12 00 0E 00 57 23
57 23 02 23 57 0A
2D 16 0C 5A 2D 16'''

# using io here for the example but use a file in the real use case
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), sep=' ', header=None, dtype=str)

x,y = df.shape

(pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(x*y//2, 2)[:, ::-1])
   .apply(''.join, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
0    0012
1    000E
2    2357
3    2357
4    2302
5    0A57
6    162D
7    5A0C
8    162D
dtype: object
```